# When No Content present, show a no content banner in TableView

Tags: ios

I am wondering how does Tumblr implement this feature. I have a tableview where I fetch data from the server, and if no content is present I want to add a banner saying, no comments, no posts, etc. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

This is how Tumblr does it

[image]

And this is my implementation so far. So instead of changing the title saying No Comments. I want a banner like Tumblr

[image]

## edit

I am not sure why this post was disliked. I clearly specified what I was looking for. I uploaded pictures to support my words as well.
This is a place to learn, atleast that is how I see it. If users get discouraged by dislikes like this, I do not think that festers a very healthy learning environment.

Comment: They use `addSubview:`

Comment: I tried adding a label as a subview, that didnt work. should I try adding a UIImage?

Comment: if tha array count is 0 hide the table view and show a uiimage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data received from the server is parsed and saved in an array for displaying on your table. So in the UITableView method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
      // put your content of the array "Show Favors" in some string and check whether the string is 

      NSString *string = [yourDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      if([yourDataArray count] <= 1 && [string isEqualToString:@"Show Favors"])
      {
           yourTableView.hidden = YES; 
           // add your banner here wherever you want to add it
      }

      else
           yourTableView.hidden = NO;


      return [yourDataArray count];

  }
```

**NOTE THAT** here I'm assuming that when you have no data from the server you have one cell that the "Show Favor" one and the title shows "No Comments". Assuming as per the image. If its something else do elaborate it in your question so that I can give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Sharanya, I always have one Cell. The Show Favors one

Comment: Sharanya, wouldn't yourTableView.hidden = YES; hide my Show Favors cell as well?

Comment: Yes, Ofcourse.. But thats what you wanted right? to hide the table? Be more clear in your explaination

Comment: I still want Show Favors cell to be there. So that user can still see who favored the post

Comment: What exactly are you looking at implementing? You want the banner which says "No Notifications" similar to tumblr one? or something diff? Coz there the table is not shown

Comment: So where do you want the banner?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26236/discussion-between-sharanya-and-jonathan)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a banner when the array count is 0.

```
if([yourArrayName count] == 0)
{
   // Code here to show banner
}
```

Comment: Akhil, I am doing that. that is how I change my title. I want a way to add a banner. I tried adding label. but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an imageview below tableview like

[self.view addSubView:someImageView]; // image view will be having that image you wat to show when there are no datasource.

& once the dataSource array count is zero, hide the tableview

[yourtableView setHidden:YES];

& once datasource array count is non zero , show the tableView.

[yourtableView setHidden:NO];